# Approximate rect after applying CATransform3D?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, frame, catransform3d

I applied `CATransform3D` to a view. How can I find its approximate new frame after it?

I mean I applied a complex transform: rotation, translation, scale and perspective. And I need to find something like approximate minimal rect. I need it because this view is added to `UIScrollView` (to know the `contentSize` I need and of course to implement "scrollToItem:")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `CGRect` that completely contains this transformed view, you can use `convertRect:toView:`. For example:

```
CGRect rect = [viewWithTransforms convertRect:viewWithTransforms.bounds toView:self.view];
```

For example, the gray view is some transformed `UIView`, and the black border is the result of `convertRect:toView:` shown above:

[image]

Comment: it is strange but in my case it show the same result as the frame property does. Don't you know if they are different?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW51), if the view is transformed, "the value of the `frame` property is undefined". I'm not surprised it's equal to `convertRect` result (which is a more generalized solution), but given that caveat in the documentation, I wouldn't use `frame` once the view is transformed. The `bounds` describes the size of the rect before the transformation.

Comment: I use your code but still when I zoom view at that time it give CGRectInfinite.

Comment: `convertRect` is returning `CGRectInfinite`? Or `frame` is?