# detect subview's frame when superview transform

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIview` with some `subviews` in it! When I transform that view (scale, rotate.. use  CATransform3D). These subviews grow bigger or smaller but the subviews do not change the frame. How can I detect the real frame of them? Thanks!

```
  viewTransfromContainer?.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale((viewTransfromContainer?.layer.transform)!, pinchGes.scale, pinchGes.scale, pinchGes.scale)
```

I used   convert(<#T##rect: CGRect##CGRect#>, to: <#T##UIView?#>) It's work fine with scale But Not return true value when rotate.

[image bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DCqX.jpg)

Comment: `frame` is unreliable when the view is transformed. Use `bound` and `center` instead.

Comment: @9dan yes, how can i assign view to a CGrect use bound and center when it transform rotated ? please help!

Comment: What code you have tried ?

Comment: If you want to move position you could change the center, for width or height change bound. That's it.

Comment: @SagarChauhan i have updated. How to detect subview's frame of viewTransfromContainer . i able to detect it when subview not transform, but if its subview is transformed i can not find.

Comment: @9dan is there any way to detect subview's frame? or superview's frame when transform

Comment: Maybe be this post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139969/approximate-rect-after-applying-catransform3d

Comment: @9dan it's not return true value.